# Criar um Download de acordo com id do elemento

Tags: java, spring, download

eu criei um sistema que faz o upload de vários arquivos, porém esbarrei no seguinte problema: eu preciso criar uma forma de realizar o download de acordo com o id do elemento no banco. Gostaria de saber se alguém tem uma ideia que eu possa aproveitar para fazer essa função. Eu criei um metodo no meu controller, porem não funcionou como eu queria.

segue o metodo que eu criei:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView downloadFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response){


    Path arquivo = Paths.get(fileName + ".pdf");

    if(Files.exists(arquivo)){

        response.setHeader(" Content-Disposition","attachment, filename=\"" + fileName + ".pdf" + "\"");
        response.setContentType(" application/pdf");
        try {

            Files.copy(arquivo, response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return new ModelAndView(REQUEST_MAPPING_PAGE_PESQUISAR_ITO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

public class Teste {

    @RequestMapping(value = "download/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadArquivo(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) throws Exception {
        byte[] file = buscaArquivoPorId(id);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "document.pdf");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setContentLength(file.length);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(file)), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: é obrigatório que o retorno seja em byte?, por que eu tenho apenas o path do arquivo no banco a imagem fica em um diretório dentro do meu web server

Answer (score 0):

Opa, eis minha solução:

```
public static final Path uploadingdir = "caminho do arquivo";

@GetMapping("/{nome:.*}")
public void downloadPDFResource(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @PathVariable("nome") String fileName) {

    Path file = Paths.get(uploadingdir.toString(), fileName);
    if (Files.exists(file)) {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        try {
            Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro baixar arquivo", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Só tem que observar o caminho do arquivo que você está buscando.

Comment: você chamaria esse metodo com um href mesmo ou pelo ajax ?

Comment: Por um href. Você precisa em um ajax?

Comment: não é uma necessidade mais acredito que pelo Ajax tenho mais controle para tratar

Comment: Na verdade, funciona com ajax sim. Testei aqui.

Comment: Então por que acredito que o meu problema esteja na hora chamada, acredito que não estou sabendo como fazer entende.

Comment: Por que ele até chega ao método, mais não realiza o download do arquivo.

Comment: Opa, conseguiu resolver seu problema?